# How to call the corresponding Java methods (for each button) written in a single eventhandler class in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, jsni

I want to call different methods (that are in a single GWT eventhandler class) on click of different buttons? It is like this:

Let's say I have 3 buttons in my UI:

1. Button1
2. Button2
3. Button3

And, I have attached the same (Click) EventHandler for each of them: ButtonClicker

And inside the OnClick() method I would like to call the methods corresponding to the button that was clicked. Here's some sample code to better illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
public class ButtonClicker implements ClickHandler 
{
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        PushButton clickedButton = (PushButton) event.getSource();

        // I could call the corresponding method using if-else condition but I do not want to do that. 
        // Instead, I want some code here, may be using JSNI (using eval in some way) or something like that to call the corresponding method.
        ......      
    }

    private void Button1Click()
    {
        // Code to handle Button1 Click 
    }

    private void Button2Click()
    {
        // Code to handle Button2 Click
    }

    private void Button3Click()
    {
        // Code to handle Button3 Click
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you routing all this through the same event handler?  This seems like it should be different event handlers, possibly subclassing an abstract event handler with common code.

Comment: I agree that it is ideal to call/write different event handler classes for different button clicks. But we want to go this route where we will have one single event handler class. I was wondering, if there is a way to call the corresponding method by using JSNI or something. Any ideas please?

Comment: What you are asking for is a very convoluted and unconventional approach.  It might be doable with JSNI but I don't recommend it.  Perhaps if you explain what is sending you down this path we can offer some better way to address all this.  Also, when you say you have Button1, Button2 and Button3 are those classes?  css class names?  html element names?

Comment: One reason is, I have atleast 30+ (different) buttons in my UI and I do not want to write different eventhandler classes for each of them. And at the same time, I want avoid the huge if-else statement that I foresee with the above approach.

Comment: You don't want a different handler, but you are okay writing a) a different method for each and b) a different `button.addClickHandler` invocation, plus the check to dispatch to the right button? Doesn't that seem contradictory to you?

Comment: For all my buttons, when I am creating them in a loop, this is how I assign the eventhandler:  button.addClickHandler(new ButtonClicker());

Comment: So why not using the classic closure style way? wrapper.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // Do whatever you want with this button
  }
});

Comment: As per our programming conventions, we are not allowed the closure way :(

Comment: And, this is what/how I am looking for. Not sure the right way but looking for a solution something on these lines:   
Class ButtonClicker
{
  public void onClick()
  {
    PushButton clickedButton = (PushButton) event.getSource();
    callJavaMethod(clickedButton.getElement().getId());
  }

  public static native void callJavaMethod(String javaMethodName) 
  /*-{
    eval('$wnd.'+ javaMethodName);
  }-*/; 
}
 
where javaMethodName will be like Button1Click() or Button2Click() etc....

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you have very good reasons to go this convoluted route, so here's a proposal, no judgement included:

```
JavaScriptObject map = createMap(this);

private static native JavaScriptObject createMap(ButtonClicker o) /*-{
   // Note: does not use $entry() as this will be called from GWT code
   return {
       "button1": function() { o.@foo.ButtonClicker::Button1Click()(); },
       "button2": function() { o.@foo.ButtonClicker::Button2Click()(); },
       "button3": function() { o.@foo.ButtonClicker::Button3Click()(); }
     };
}-*/;

private static native void call(JavaScriptObject map, String id) /*-{
  var fn = map[id];
  // TODO: add null-check / fallback behavior
  fn();
}-*/;

@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  call(map, ((UIObject) event.getSource()).getElement().getId());
}
```

Comment: That worked (except for a small hiccup with the "call" method" - it was required to wrap the body of this method between /* and */ as it was a native method.) Not really sure what overhead this poses as compared to calling the methods with a simple if-else (or a switch) statement. Anyways, Thank you for your time and solution.

Comment: Fixed the `call()` method, thanks. In terms of overhead compared to chained `if`/`else`, it'll depend on the browser JS engine and the number of cases, but there shouldn't be a significant difference. Note that Java7 support should come in the next version of GWT and you'll be able to use strings-in-switch \o/

Comment: Thanks @Tom. Anyways, just wondering, if something like this is possible: (inside createMap)                                                                 var x = methodName;
     var y = 'function() { o.@foo.ButtonClicker::'+x+'()(); }';
This way, I don't need the implicit switch (kind of) statement as in the above createMap function.

Comment: Ah no, impossible. BTW, you know UiBinder and its `@UiHandler`, right?

Comment: I am aware of UiBinder but never used it. In any case, I guess I cannot go with it, as I think, I have to use an XML for building the UI, which is a no-no at our place.

Comment: Judgement inside: no anonymous classes and no UiBinder? your coding standards suck; coding standards should be about getting everyone on the same track so it's not "one's code" or "the other's code" (it's just "the code"); it shouldn't be about limiting your expressiveness and slowing you down!